# In need to capitalize the 3rd letter of this string

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x=input("enter word=")
if x[2]=="a":
x[2]="A"
```

Also help if you know how do i make a function to capitalise every even position on a word.To MaKe It LiKe THiS

Answer (score 1):

Try this to capitalize the 3rd letter of the string `x` :

```
x = input("enter word=")
if x[2].islower():
    x = x[:2] + x[2].upper() + x[3:]
```

Comment: Thnx,can you explain the logic of that last line,I do under stand .isupper or .is lower but what is [:2 :3]and whay is it all adding?

Comment: @NasrUllah It's string concatenation. If the 3rd char is lower cased, we take the first 2 chars, uppercase the 3rd char, and take the rest of the chars and then join these to form a new string and assign it to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this -

x2=x[:2] + x[2].upper() + x[3:]

Answer (score 1):

The function **capitalise** will help you to capitalise the 3rd character of every word. If word has lesser than 3 chars then it will return the string without modification.

```
def capitalise(x):
  chars = list(x)
  if len(x) > 2:
    chars[2] = chars[2].upper()
  return ''.join(chars)

x = raw_input("enter word=")
x = capitalise(x)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=input("enter word=")
if len(x)>3:
   x = x[:2] + x[2].upper() + x[3:]
```

You should check for the length of the string, otherwise you will get an error if the word has less than 3 characters